# example to override getValueFieldProperties FilterBuilder

Tags: smartgwt

I want to override getValueFieldProperties for FilterBuilde. 
      My requirement is for some specific type of field I want to show selection, for Value field instead of simple text box.
      I have visited following:
      http://code.google.com/p/smartgwt/source/browse/tags/2.5/main/src/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/FilterBuilder.java?r=1796

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the requirement `requirement is, for some specific type of field, I want to show selection, for Value field instead of simple text box.`

```
for (DataSourceField field : dataSource.getFields()) {

    String type = field.getAttribute("serverType");

    if (type!=null && type.equals("SPECIFIC_TYPE")) {

    TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    map.put("1", "value 1");
    map.put("2", "value 2");
    field.setValueMap(map);
    }
}
```